# how to create(construct) a json file from python

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to create(not to modify, the file does not exist yet) a json file from python 3.6, and give a specific name, I have read that using open(file, "a"), if the file does not exist, the method will create it. the method bellow will run ok, but will not create the file, any idea on how to resolve this.

I have tried the following :

```
def create_file(self):
        import os
        monthly_name = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%Y')
        file=monthly_name + ".json"
        file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)
        if not os.path.exists(file_path) or new_file:
            print("Creating file...")
            try:
                open(file, "a")
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `a` mode is for appending. How can you append to a file that doesn't exist? Thus, this mode does not create the file. You want `w` mode.

Comment: What operating system? That should create the file; you just never wrote any data to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build JSON from python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456255/how-to-build-json-from-python-script)

Comment: you can also do `a+` as this will to create a new file @kindall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `a` (append) mode here.

Also, since it's bad practice to catch exceptions only to print them and continue, I've elided that bit too.

Instead, the function *will* raise an exception if it were about to overwrite an existing file.

Since your date format `%Y/%m` creates a subdirectory, e.g. the path will end up being

> something/2019/04.json

you'll need to make sure the directories inbetween exist. `os.makedirs` does that.

```py
import os
import json

# ...


def create_file(self):
    monthly_name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m")
    file_path = monthly_name + ".json"
    file_dir = os.path.dirname(file_path)  # Get the directory name from the full filepath
    os.makedirs(file_dir, exist_ok=True)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise RuntimeError("file exists, not overwriting")
    with open(file_path, "w") as fp:
        json.dump({"my": "data"}, fp)
```

Comment: this definitely works, @AKX what can I change to leave the file in the same directory ?

Comment: Change your "monthly_name" pattern to something that doesn't have a slash, e.g. `%Y-%m`.